# Defaulting to full-screen in Cocoa app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, osx-lion

I've seen a ton of posts about adding a control to a NSWindow to give it the ability to go into full-screen — both through code and Interface Builder settings. What I'm looking for is when the application is launched, it opens in full-screen by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set your main window's delegate.  You can use your app delegate as the window delegate if you don't already have a window delegate.  Then add this method to the window delegate:

```
- (void)windowDidBecomeMain:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    static BOOL shouldGoFullScreen = YES;
    if (shouldGoFullScreen) {
        if (!([self.window styleMask] & NSFullScreenWindowMask))
            [self.window toggleFullScreen:nil];
        shouldGoFullScreen = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are coding for older versions of OS. you can use the below code.This code will work from 10.6 mac lion onwords.

```
 [self.window setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary];
 [[NSApplication sharedApplication] setPresentationOptions:NSFullScreenWindowMask];
```